# Query string JWT JSON Web Token Authentication in PHP Slim API

Tags: php, api, authentication, jwt, slim

This is a question about the best way of implementing JWT in a Slim PHP API - I'm looking for some guidance from senior/experienced developers as to how to proceed.

I currently have an open API, where users can perform get requests with query parameters such as device and date-time range to pull data. I also have devices which are POSTing data, with no authentication. We're not in production yet, but obviously this is bad.

To tackle this, I've been looking at implementing stateless authentication on the GET requests in the first case, specifically using JWT. I initially thought about passing the JWT through as a query string, with options for resetting a token performed through the web front-end after a user has logged in. However, I can see this being bad for man-in-the-middle attacks and my token being exposed (if using plain http). If I was to make sure all get/post requests were performed as https requests, will this be sufficiently secure?

What seems to be the more secure way would be to pass the token through the header. But from what I understand about this, you'd need something like Postman to be able to send requests, which isn't really an option since my users want to access the data using their browser only.

Answer (score 0):

It's pointless using http, https is a must otherwise everyone in between the user and your server will see the password the responses can even be cached.

The token can be stored in a secure cookie which the browser will automatically include with each request. (The Slim Middleware for JWT has this functionality built in). Check out many available libraries at https://jwt.io/

Adding the token to the query string isn't needed if you use cookies, I would not recommend adding tokens to the query string as they are to easily leaked.
(Users love copy&pasting URLs to each other, this would also leak the token)

Note: If you're not sure if JWT is right for you, check out: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/